# print to gedit whit xdotool

Tags: linux, xdotool

I want to read the content of a text file, copy it to the clipboard (if it is not empty) and then paste to the `gedit` window where the mouse cursor is positioned.

Here is my script:

```
while true
do
  if [ -s textfile ]
  then
    cat textfile | xclip -selection clipboard
    xdotool key --clearmodifiers Control_L+v
    truncate -s 0 textfile
  fi
done
```

All works except `xdotool`:

- If i press manually CTRL+v it paste correctly.
- If i run xev i can see that xdotool send the correct keyboard events, but nothing happen.

I have tried some other commands, like:

- `xdotool key ctrl+v`
- `xdotool type $(xclip -selection clipboard -o)`
- `xdotool getactivewindow type $(xclip -selection clipboard -o)`, that gives me the error `XGetWindowProperty[_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW] failed (code=1)`
- `sleep 1 && xdotool key Control_L+v`

No Luck.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Are you sure xdotool allows the `--clearmodifiers` option _between_ `key` and the actual keyspec?

Comment: btw., I don't see exactly what you are trying to achieve, but I would at least add a delay in that loop, something like `sleep 0.25`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the problem was that Libx11-dev was missing. Once the library was installed, the script worked correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
xdotool type "$(xclip -o)"
```